# Sql Query for taking backup in MSAccess 2007?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

Is there any sql query for MS-Access database to take backup directly from c#Application?
if not,then how to do it from c#Application?

i am developing a C#.net application with access as back-end.

now what i want is, a sql query so that when i execute it i so should get a backup file in a folder.

i have tried it in sql server using query "BACKUP DATABASE AdventureWorks TO DISK = 'C:\AdventureWorks.BAK';"
But i don't know how to do it in Ms MS-Access?
please help.

Comment: Just copy the MS-Access file to a different location ?

Comment: What habib says. Why bother puttering around with some sql when you could just do `copy original.mdb backup.mdb` and be done with it?

Comment: when we take backup the resulting file size will be lesser then the actual file ,and when your file is significantly large then this method will not be feasible i guess.

Comment: Microsoft Access is a single file database system. You don't have any built in function in JET-SQL to create a backup of the database itself. As others have said you simple copy the database in another location. If the size of the database is big (however Access has a 2gb limits) then you could ZIP it before storing away the zipped file. I have used [this library](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) (I am not involved in any way with the author)

Comment: thank you steve for expalining in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Access is a single file database system. You don't have any built in function in JET-SQL to create a backup of the database itself. As others have said you simple copy the database in another location. If the size of the database is big (however Access has a 2gb limits) then you could ZIP it before storing away the zipped file.

I have used this library [DotNetZip at CodePlex](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) (I am not involved in any way with the author)

```
void Main()
{
    CopyToZip(@"D:\temp\temp.accdb", @"D:\temp\temp.zip");
}
private static void CopyToZip(string source, string dest)
{
     using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(dest))
     {
         ZipEntry e = zip.UpdateFile(source, string.Empty);
         e.Comment = "Database archived in date: " + DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
         zip.Save();
     }
}
```

An advice. Remember to close any connection before executing the backup. MS-Access has not a bullet-proof log and recovery system like its big cousin, and if any thread is writing to the database while you take a backup, the result is probably a corrupted file

Comment: can you please tell me how to close all the connection before taking the backup? i googled it but did not got it for access. and thank you for the code.

Comment: In a single user situation this should not be a problem. If you follow the best practice to open/use/close your connection then you should be safe. Otherwise, you have a global OleDbConnection instance that you should check for closed state. In a multiuser scenario this is tricky because no provision is present to take a safe backup. The only thing that comes to mind is trying to open the connection in Exclusive Mode (`Mode=Share Exclusive`) and if you succeed then you are relatively safe to make your move. (However I really hope you don't force Access in a high concurrency situation)